# How can I convert binary bits into index in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dynamic-programming

I have a question regarding how to use the binary bits as an index in MATLAB, For example, if I'm using 4 antennas to transmit data, in each instant, one antenna or two are active to transmit the data. how can I use the indexing of antennas to transmit that symbol, here an example as below:

```
%Suppose I'm using for antennas to transmit that data. 
Nt = 4;          % Number of antennas
Symbole = 1+j;    % The symbol to transmit in binary after modulation

Ant_index = 11;  % The antenna index which will be used to transmit data. (here number 3 will be used)
x_trans =zeros(Nt,1); % Initialization of antennas 
x_trans(Ant_index) = Symbole;     %Use the antenna to transmit the data
```

My question is in the last step, `x_trans(Ant_index) = Symbole;`I want to use the binary bits as index, which means, instead of the bits `Ant_index = 11` which means 3 in decimal, I want to use the two bits as antennas for transmitting the same symbol. for example if I have bits 0101 , It means I will use the antenna number 1 and number 3 to transmit the symbol in the same above example `Ant_index = 0011`. it means that first and second antennas will be used to transmit the Symbol.

EDIT:

Second part of question, what's about if the generated bits for antenna indexing are generated randomly. and we want to avoid having the `Ant_index = 000`; in other words,  we need the  `Ant_index` to be as decimal value, and then make mapping for `000` which is in decimal 0, the antenna 1 should be activated, `001 = 1` ---> antenna 2 should be activated. `010 = 2` ---> antenna 3 active, `011 = 3` ---> antenna 4 active. `100 = 4` ---> antennas 1 and 2 are active, `101 = 5` ---> antennas 1 and 3 are active, and so on.

Comment: What is the range of the randomly generated `Ant_index` ?

Comment: The range is 000 to 111, and I have the antennas are 4

Comment: This gives you only 7 possible values, it is not enough to cover all your cases. If you can have any combination of 2 antennas active (out of 4) at a time you would need a minimum of 10 values (11 values if you also allow the case 'no antenna active').

Comment: Hello My friend, I think I got that,, It's done..  but I got strange trace. I think the issue in calculating the Euclidean distance. I posted another detailed question in here,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53743618/how-to-calculate-the-euclidean-distance-in-matlab .. Please if you have any idea, I will be appreciated.

Comment: I think I will have enough value, for example, if I have the value 7, which is 111 .. so that antenna to transmit are 2 and 3.  for examlple. 0 --> antenna 1 active. 1 --> antenna 2 active. 2 --> antenna 3 active.  3 --> antenna 4 active,  4--> antennas 1 and 2 active,  5 --> antennas  1 and 3 active, 6 --> antennas  1 and 4 active and finally 7 --> antennas  2  and 3 active

Comment: nope, you still miss 2 antenna configurations at the minimum [a2+a4] and [a3+a4] ...

Comment: Yes I know ...  But no need to use them since we have transmitted all bits combinations which are from 000 till 111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the desired format of your input, you can use one of the 2 decimal to binary conversion function:

- [`de2bi`](https://mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/de2bi.html) => return
  an array of `0` and `1`, representing the binary number.
- [`dec2bin`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html) =>
  return a string representation of the binary number.

---

**Conversion**:

I recommend using `de2bi` since an array will be easier to convert into indices. For example:
activate antenna 1 and 2 (`3` decimal == `11` in binary):

```
>> de2bi(3) % index antenna 1 and 2 (`3` decimal == `11` in binary):
ans =
     1     1
>> de2bi(10) % index antenna 2 and 4 (`10` decimal == `1010` in binary):
ans =
     0     1     0     1
```

Note that by default `de2bi` return the binary representation in *small endian* bit ordering (the first element in the array represents the lowest bit). This is a bit the opposite of our visual convention, there is a parameter to reverse that, but for your purpose it is already exactly what we want. It saves us from reading the array from right to left or reversing it.

---

**Indexing:**
You said you have 4 antenna, but for this example I'll enlarge that a bit. Let's say you need to control 7 antenna. It would mean I always have to have an array of indices conataining 7 elements. No problem, `de2bi` allows you to specifiy the number of output digits. So again, to activate antenna 2 and 4 (out of seven):

```
>> Nt=7;
>> Ant_index = de2bi(10,Nt)
Ant_index =
     0     1     0     1     0     0     0
```

with that you can directly use your index to transmit data:

```
x_trans(Ant_index) = Symbole;
```

---

**Input format:**

This is all and well if you know your elementary binary table up to your number of antenna. In case you want to be able to specify active antennas with a binary representation instead of a direct decimal number, you can use the reverse conversion function, more specifically [`bin2dec`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bin2dec.html)
So a last example to show you how they all work together:

```
>> stringAntIndex = '1010'
stringAntIndex =
1010

decimalAntIndex = bin2dec(stringAntIndex)
decimalAntIndex =
    10

>> Ant_index = de2bi(decimalAntIndex,7)
Ant_index =
     0     1     0     1     0     0     0
```

Which of course you could simplify to:

```
>> stringAntIndex = '1010' ;
>> Ant_index = de2bi(bin2dec(stringAntIndex),Nt)
Ant_index =
     0     1     0     1     0     0     0
```

---

**Edit:** Ok I place the answer to your updated question here to finish it but note that your edited question is completely different than your original question. What you are asking now has nothing to do with converting bits into indices, it is just a straight mapping which you have to define before hand (since it doesn't follow any computation logic).
Basically, store your active antenna indices in a cell array, and pick the the cell corresponding to your randomly generated index (you'll have to add 1 because MATLAB starts array indices at `1`, not at `0` like many other languages.
So:

```
% Map the antenna to be active depending on decimal input
Antenna2Activate = {
    [1] ;   % antenna 1 active
    [2] ;   % antenna 2 active
    [3] ;   % ...
    [4] ;   % ...
    [1 2] ; % antenna 1 & 2 active
    [1 3] ; % antenna 1 & 3 active
    [1 4] ; % ...
    [2 3]   % antenna 2 & 3 active
    };

% Then to activate the proper antenna given a decimal input [decimalInput]:
Ant_index = Antenna2Activate{ decimalInput+1 } ;
x_trans(Ant_index) = Symbole;
```

To make sure it works the way you want, you can run the following code:

```
decinput = 0:7 ;
for k=1:numel(Antenna2Activate)
    Ant_index = Antenna2Activate{ decinput(k)+1 } ;
    fprintf('Decimal input= %d \t Binary= %3s \t Ant_index: ',decinput(k),dec2bin(decinput(k),3))
    disp(Ant_index)
end
```

Which yields:

```
Decimal input= 0     Binary= 000     Ant_index:      1
Decimal input= 1     Binary= 001     Ant_index:      2
Decimal input= 2     Binary= 010     Ant_index:      3
Decimal input= 3     Binary= 011     Ant_index:      4
Decimal input= 4     Binary= 100     Ant_index:      1     2
Decimal input= 5     Binary= 101     Ant_index:      1     3
Decimal input= 6     Binary= 110     Ant_index:      1     4
Decimal input= 7     Binary= 111     Ant_index:      2     3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that detailed explanation. unfortunately I can't vote up for your answer :( , because I'm still new in this community group. .  But I need a clarification, I have the `Ant_index`   is generated randomly, so what's about if it was 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ? for that I asked if we can make it in decimal, it means if it's  in decimal 0, which means in binary (0 0 0 0 0 0 0), so the antenna 1 will be activated, if it's 1 , which means in binary (0 0 0 0 0 0 1), the antenna 2, if it's 8 which means in binary (0 0 0 1 0 0 0), the antenna 1 and 2 will be activated, and so on.

Comment: @New_student. Whichever `Ant_index` is randomly generated, the function `de2bi` will convert the decimal number into a reverse array of bits, which is more or less the title of your question. I don't understand, why a decimal value of `8` (`0001000` in binary) would activate antenna 1 and 2. I was under the impression that it should activate antenna 4.

Comment: So sorry for that misunderstanding, I mean  suppose if we have the generated bits `0 (0000000)`, will that mean we don't have any activated antennas? So to avoid that,  what I mean, it will be as following :  0 --> antenna 1, 1 --> antenna 2 , 3 --> antenna 4 , 4 --> antenna 5, 5 --> antenna 6, 6 -->antenna 7, 7 --> antennas 1 and 2, 8 --> antennas 1 and 3 and so on.

Comment: Man you are completely changing your original question. Please modify your original question by adding the information from your latest comment. I'll update my answer later today to take the new requirements into account.

Comment: Also, I don't know the details of your system, but it is quite common for a system to have an "inactive" state. So yes if you send `0`, in the current version, no antenna would be active. So it acts like a handy "off" switch ... How else would you turn the antenna off? also, how is the `Ant_index` randomly generated? Do you control this generation? If yes you could just prevent the generator to ouput the value `0`... easier than to have to offset all your results ...

Comment: Thank you dear, Ok, I'll add that part of question into the question. thanks again

Comment: I really appreciate your help. thank you so much dear ..  yes that what I looked for, is how to map that antennas to be activated. I've read your modification right now. but I encountered an issue in the calculation of Euclidean distance !! I mean how can I detect which antenna as activated and its correspondent bits. I wrote that in that post you asked me to modify it again.

Comment: I'm checking that point, I think we should use the array called Antenna2Activate in order to calculate the minimum Euclidean distance based on the received symbols. but what I did in my code is just to calculate the Euclidean distance without taking care of that array Antenna2Activate !  I'm not sure if that right or not. !

Comment: I got banned of asking more questions, please upvote my  question to enable me to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0):

You do ant_index = [0,0,1,1] for transmitting the symbol on antenna 1 and 2. Then do x_trans(ant_index == 1) = symbol. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, of course that helped. but it's not ant_index = [0,0,1,1], ant_index = 0011, it's random bits, and that's ok, it worked also with that. .  what's about if the ant_index  is decimal, can I do that also? for example if 1 first antenna active, if 6, so 110 second and third antenna are active, I mean the same thing of the above question except that number is decimal. how can I do that? Is that possible too?